# How to allow everyone to see the posts I am tagged in?

Tags: facebook

How can I allow public to see the posts I am tagged in on my timeline? Looking here:

[image]

I can only set friends to see them, but not public! In the custom option, I can only add "friends of friends", but not total public. The option "everyone" seems missing here.

Answer (score 4):

The option "Everyone" is not there because if you are tagged in someone's post, and that person doesn't want make it public, you also can't make it public.

Comment: Hmm, but the option is global and not post specific... what if the person made the particular post public? The option is obviously still missing.

Comment: In that case you can make that tag visible to friends or costume audience or only me.

Comment: "what if the person made the particular post public?" - then presumably it's already public?